# How many types can std::variant define?

Tags: c++, variant, c++17

I've learned there is a [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) type in c++17. 
Looks like there are no predefined data types supported by the variant container but for each variant type the user may define her own data-type set.

```
std::variant<int, float> v;
```

I wonder, how long may the list of types be? Does the library has a predefined templates for a maximal number of parameter in Aleksandrescu manner, or is the variant supported by the compiler and the number of types is not limited?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximum number of template parameters is limited by the compiler implementation.

[The C++ standard says](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/limits.html):

> Because computers are finite, C ++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs they
>   can successfully process. Every implementation shall document those limitations where known. This docu
>   mentation may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to compute variable limits as a function of available
>   resources, or say that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown.
>
> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others. **The bracketed number
>   following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are
>   only guidelines and do not determine compliance.**
>
> ...
>
> Template arguments in a template declaration [1024]

Comment: "The maximum number of template parameters is limited by the compiler implementation"  - that's true, but does it apply to std::variant? Doesn't std::variant has its own limitation by the implementation?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Answers to your two questions: it does; AFAIK not.

Comment: ОК, great! So it's truly a new C++11 compiler feature not an add-on to the library like boost.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz `std` implementation of `variant` uses variadic templates which is limited by the compiler limits. Pre-C++11 `boost` implementation used a fixed number of template parameters.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Seems you erroneously think, that `std::variant` is built-in type.

Comment: @Orient Note the compiler is free to implement `std::variant` as a built-in type, so long as it behaves as-if the standard dictates.  `std::make_index_sequence` in MSVC2015, for example, is done with built-in operations to generate the resulting sequence, rather than implemented in template meta programming.

Comment: @Yakk It may worth the effort to implement it, say, in `clang++`. How difficult task is it, what do you think?